# YouTube Embed Shows Different Video in Various Browsers

Tags: youtube

I've got a YouTube video I'm embedding in an iFrame.  Here's the embed URL:

http://www.youtube.com/embed/-3W3xvAcD2Y

In the current versions of Safari, Mobile Safari, and Firefox on my Mac I get a doubled video (3D version?) once the video actually starts playing, as shown below:[image: Error Embed]
(Note: the preview image looks normal, you have to actually start playing the video before it doubles like this.)

In Chrome I get the correct version: [image: Good Embed]
Both are using the HTML5 player FWIW, and these embed links have been working for me until recently.  I see the same results when actually embedding the links in an iFrame; it's just easier to link to the embed URL here.  In my testing, I don't see this for all YouTube videos; it might be limited to videos that have been uploaded recently, but I'm not 100% sure on that (here's [another example](http://www.youtube.com/embed/sCnB5azFmTs) that shows the problem).

Any idea what is going on?  Could this be an embed code error on YouTube that popped up recently?  Give that URL a try and let me know if how it works on other browsers.

Comment: I've reported this issue to YouTube as a bug, but I have no idea how responsive they'll be.  Hopefully it's fixed soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same problem.

Looks like YouTube is forcing 3D on embeds for random HTML5 videos. I noticed mozstereomode="1" is being applied on videos that are having this issue.

Comment: I'm glad to know someone else is seeing the same issue, but I'm still hoping YouTube fixes this or to figure out some work around.  I tried setting mozstereomode to 0 via a URL argument and that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now in a quick test I did.  Let me know if it's fixed for you.  If so we can mark this down as a temporary bug and I'll give you credit for the solution.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the bug is fixed! Awesome that they resolved this so quickly!